# F# transforming and aggregating a list of lists

Tags: f#

I have the following set of data

```
let results = [[true;false;true];[true;true;false];[false;false;false]]
```

I want to turn it into

```
let summary = [2;1;1]
```

Is this something that can be done of the box?  I was thinking the List.Collect but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify how is the boolean calculated from the source list?

Comment: LOL.  I wish I could clarify it myself!  The source list is series of values and I compare if each value contains certain other values.  Would it help if I posted the functions to that point?

Comment: Well, I wrote something that produces the result you gave for the input you gave, but I have no idea if that's what you wanted :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your sample, I suppose that you want to sum the number of `true` values in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. elements of the input lists, respectively.

One way to do this is to turn the list of booleans into list of numbers containing ones or zeros and then aggregate the lists. So, for your input, the list with numbers will be:

```
[[1; 0; 1]; [1; 1; 0]; [0; 0; 0]]
```

This we can easily get using nested `List.map`:

```
results |> List.map (List.map (fun b -> if b then 1 else 0))
```

Now you just need to zip the lists and add their corresponding numbers. Given the first two lists, you can do it using `List.map2` as follows:

```
List.map2 (+) [1; 0; 1] [1; 1; 0] = [2; 1; 1]
```

The whole thing can be written as a single nice pipeline using partial application:

```
results
|> List.map (List.map (fun b -> if b then 1 else 0))
|> List.reduce (List.map2 (+))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll include it in my blog later this week (assuming I can finish this).  I have an Apriori Algorithm 50% done...  I think I have spent 15 hours on it this weekend and I have 57 lines of code...